# View.OnKeyListener worked once for my activity, does not work anymore

Tags: android

I have an Activity that implemented `View.OnKeyListener` so that it could catch when the user hit the back button and would pop up a dialog. Previously, it worked just fine. Recently, however, it has stopped working and the app would just pretend that there was no `onKey` method to catch the Back button. I can't seem to figure out why, as I've barely touched the `onKey` method since I made the changes. I tried just using `OnBackPressed()` instead, but that didn't solve anything and in fact created weird and unpredictable behavior. Can anyone help me figure out why it seems like my app is letting the system take the reigns on the back button?

Here's the important parts of my implementation:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class NagTasksAddTasksActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {
    //various parameters
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String setTheme = prefs.getString("themeselect", "Dark Overflow");
        if (setTheme.toLowerCase().contentEquals("dark overflow")){
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_ForceOverflow);
        } else if (setTheme.toLowerCase().contentEquals("light overflow")){
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_ForceOverflow);
            isDarkThemeUsed = false;
        } else if (setTheme.toLowerCase().contentEquals("dark menu")){
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        } else if (setTheme.toLowerCase().contentEquals("light menu")){
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);
            isDarkThemeUsed = false;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.createtasklayout);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setTitle(R.string.newTask);

    }
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.wait);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmbackkey);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //stuff
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.discard, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder subBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
                    subBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    subBuilder.setTitle(R.string.wait);
                    subBuilder.setMessage(R.string.confirmdiscard);
                    subBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //more stuff
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    subBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    subBuilder.create().show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to catch the back button is to use the dispatchKeyEvent method in the Activity (you don't need to implement View.OnKeyListener).  This seems to work for me every time.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity
{
...

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
    {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) 
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    Log.v("myApp", "Back button pressed.");
                    return true;
                }
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small question: shouldn't the `return` be with the `case` statement? Similar to how you're supposed to configure `OnOptionsItemSelected()`?

Comment: Yes it definitely should be.  I suppose something like this is a cleaner solution.  This way I'm returning false unless the key event actually does something...

Comment: Well, this works. And it also shows that I have other bugs to find. Excuse me.

Comment: Instead of 'return false' you probably want to do `return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return true` under `builder.create().show();` and change the `return false` into `return true` and see if it works. this should let them all to return results when a KeyEvent is initialized.

Comment: ...Wouldn't that intercept EVERY key press and make them do nothing? I mean, I know I'm just doing this for testing purposes, but that still sounds stupid dangerous.

Comment: Wouldn't return true let a KeyEvent return results?

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) suggests you return true for `onKey()` if you have handled the KeyEvent and that the OS doesn't need to. Currently, the code is set up to return true only if the back button is pressed (at least it's supposed to) and to return false elsewise. Changing it to always return true would mean that the OS would never handle any keyEvents on that activity ever.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to override OnBackPressed and fill in the code you want to have happen when someone presses the back button.

just make sure you delete the super.OnBackPressed line.

Comment: "I tried just using `OnBackPressed()` instead, but that didn't solve anything and in fact created weird and unpredictable behavior." - Quote from my question.